# SQLAlchemy (psycopg2.OperationalError) fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm having this authentication issue when trying to connect to a postgres db using sqlalchemy.
This is how I'm connection:

```
db_url = 'postgresql+psycopg2:///<role>:<pass>@localhost:5432/basketball'
Engine = create_engine(db_url, echo=False)
SessionMaker = ORM.sessionmaker(bind=Engine, autoflush=False)
Session = ORM.scoped_session(SessionMaker)
```

This is how I set up `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Then, when accessing the db I get:

```
SQLAlchemy  (psycopg2.OperationalError) fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Comment: Try removing one of the slashes in the URL? It's only supposed to have two slashes (`//`) not three (`///`).

Answer (score 0):

As [@univerio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341730/univerio) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293809/sqlalchemy-psycopg2-operationalerror-fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied#comment58318157_35293809), the problem is the structure of the connection url.

The standard url structure is

```
dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database
```

The url

```py
db_url = 'postgresql+psycopg2:///<role>:<pass>@localhost:5432/basketball'
```

describes a Postgresql database named `<role>:<pass>@localhost:5432/basketball` with no explicit credentials or hostname defined, hence the error message.